# Java error = is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, arrays, interface, abstract

> im have and error Ikan is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method setName  class Ikan extends Animal implements Pet and Kucing is
>   not abstract and does not override abstract method setName  class
>   Kucing extends Animal implements Pet

```
abstract class Animal {
    protected int Legs;
    protected String Eater;
    Animal (int l,String e) {
        Legs = l;
        Eater = e;
    }
    abstract public void walk ();
    abstract public void eat ();
    int getLegs () {
        return Legs;
    }
    String getEater () {
        return Eater;
    }
}

interface Pet {
    void setName();
    String getName();
    void balikNama();
    void play();
}

class Ikan extends Animal implements Pet {
    String name,mainan;
    Ikan (int l,String e) {
        super(l,e);
    }
    void setMainan (String m) {
        mainan = m;
    }
    void getMainan () {
        System.out.println ("Ikan ini bermain"+mainan);
    }
    public void setName (String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
    public void balikNama () {
        for (String part : name.split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    public void play () {
        System.out.println (name+" lagi mainan "+mainan);
    }
    public void walk () {
        System.out.println ("Tidak bisa berjalan bisanya renang");
    }
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println ("Hewan ini memakan "+Eater);
    }
}

class Kucing extends Animal implements Pet {
    String name,mainan;
    Kucing (int l,String e) {
        super(l,e);
    }
    void setMainan (String m) {
        mainan = m;
    }
    void getMainan () {
        System.out.println ("Kucing ini bermain"+mainan);
    }
    public void setName (String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
    public void balikNama () {
        for (String part : name.split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    public void play () {
        System.out.println (name+" lagi mainan "+mainan);
    }
    public void walk () {
        System.out.println ("Berjalan dengan "+Legs+" kaki");
    }
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println ("Hewan ini memakan "+Eater);
    }
}

class Laba extends Animal {
    String name;
    Laba (int l,String e) {
        super(l,e);
    }
    void setName (String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
    public void balikNama () {
        for (String part : name.split(" ")) {
            System.out.println(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
        }
    }
    public void walk () {
        System.out.println ("Berjalan dengan "+Legs+" kaki");
    }
    public void racun () {
        System.out.println ("Cuma sedikit racunya");
    }
    public void eat () {
        System.out.println ("Hewan ini memakan "+Eater);
    }
}

class Tarantula extends Laba{
    String name;
    Tarantula (int l,String e,String n) {
        super(l,e);
        name = n;
    }
    void setName (String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
    public void balikNama () {
        for (String part : name.split(" ")) {
            System.out.println(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
        }
    }
    public void walk () {
        System.out.println ("Berjalan dengan "+Legs+" kaki");
    }
    public void racun () {
        System.out.println ("Banyak racunya");
    }

}

class TestAnimal {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Ikan I = new Ikan (0,"Manusia");
        Kucing K = new Kucing (4,"Ikan");
        Laba L = new Laba (6,"Kucing");
        Tarantula T = new Tarantula (6,"Burung","Joni");
        I.setName ("Piranha");
        K.setName ("Tiger");
        L.setName ("Spiderman");
        I.setMainan ("Ikan lainnya");
        K.setMainan ("Burung");
        Animal [] A = new Animal [4];
        A[0] = I;
        A[1] = K;
        A[2] = L;
        A[3] = T;
        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
            if (A[i] instanceof Laba) {
                System.out.println ("Ini bukan hewan peliharaan bro");
                System.out.print ("Laba laba ini bernama "+A[i].getName());
                A[i].balikNama();
                A[i].walk();
                A[i].racun();
                A[i].eat();
            } else {
                A[i].getName();
                A[i].balikNama();
                A[i].walk();
                A[i].eat();
                A[i].getMainan();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: i dont know how to fix it, please help me

Answer (score 2):

The `Pet` interface declares that `setName` should take no parameters. This is incorrect; the method is intended to take one `String` representing the new name.

Change it to

```
void setName(String name);
```

and Java will see that it has been implemented.

Comment: its work,and then i have error TestAnimal.java:167: cannot find symbol System.out.print ("Laba laba ini bernama "+A[i].getName())
Symbol : method getName() Location: class Animal

Comment: @user3424447: Try to debug this one yourself. You're going to run into more bugs, and if you keep asking StackOverflow immediately for every one, you're not going to learn to debug.

Comment: ok,thanks you very much,but after 30 error,just left 6 error now,and im still confusing how to put method from interface to array in object abstract array

Answer (score 0):

The classes Ikan and Kucing don't implement the inherited abstract method `Pet.setName()`.

Change the interface to `Pet.setName(String name)`.